# Customized email for confirmation

Tags: customer-portal

Salesforce sends confirmation email when a customer portal user signs up.

Can we customize this email?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it would seem so, take a look at this section of the [docs](http://na13.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customer_portal_enabling_features_settings.htm). Under **Email Notification Settings
Setting**.

Comment: salesforce by default sends username and passoword (temprary). I want to remove username and want to show nickname. Can we do that?

Answer (score 2):

From the docs: 
New User Template
The email template used to send a username and initial password to all newly enabled and self-registering Customer Portal users. By default, a sample template is automatically selected for you. To create your own template or modify the sample, see Managing Email Templates. This template must be marked as Available for Use.

To manage your personal email templates, 
click Your Name | Setup | Email | My Templates.
If you have permission to manage public email templates, click Your 
Name | Setup | Communication Templates | Email Templates.

Click on the name of any email template to go to the Viewing Email Templates page.
To edit or delete a template, click Edit or Del next to the template name in the list.
Click New Template to create any type of email template.

http://na13.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/admin_emailtemplates.htm